# How to order a query by sum of two columns in Ecto?

Tags: elixir, ecto

Trying to do something like this:

```
(from f in Foo,
 where: f.bar >= ^bar,
 order_by: f.cost1 + f.cost2,
 limit: 1) |> Repo.one
```

But it doesn't like the order by complaining about an invalid expression.

Also tried this:

```
(from f in Foo,
 select: %{id: id, total: fragment("cost1 + cost2 as total")},
 order_by: f.total,
 limit: 1) }> Repo.one
```

This one doesn't says column "f.total" does not exist.

Any ideas how to make this query work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure why Ecto doesn't support `order_by: f.cost1 + f.cost2`, but your `fragment` syntax is incorrect. Here's the correct syntax:

```
(from f in Foo,
 where: f.bar >= ^bar,
 order_by: fragment("? + ?", f.cost1, f.cost2),
 limit: 1) |> Repo.one
```